# Magento 2.4 admin panel won't open

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento2.4, two-factor-authentication

I have installed Magento 2.4 community version, and here I went to the admin panel and tried to log in and its show like this.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below commands to disable `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` module.

`php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 0):

For a more elegant solution the following module will let you disable/enable 2FA from the command line or admin:

[DisableTwoFactorAuth](https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth)